# Display with rapidly updating parameters in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been working with Pyserial and tkinter to obtain dual channel serial data @ 9600 and 38400 baudrates. I have a loop that will gather the data into lists, and I'd like to display the data as it comes in for the user to view in real time. The data is 24 parameters, so ideally I'd like to have a constant display of the list of parameter names next to the continuously updating values. Printing them would scroll them on the terminal display and wouldn't be ideal for the user. What could I use to create an updating display of parameters?

Comment: Isn't this the exact same question you asked earlier and was closed? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65673201/rapidly-updating-text-display-of-parameters-in-python. If it's the same question, you need to edit the original question to address the reason why it was closed.

Comment: I did edit the original question and the result is what you see. The original question still shows as closed.

Comment: You should never have created the second question. Please edit your original question to make it fall more in line with site policies. Your original question can be reopened once you've modified it.

Comment: I did modify the original question.

Comment: Yes, I see, but you didn't modify it in a way that makes it a valid question. It's just too broad, asking for opinions on how to do something. "What could I use?" is asking for opinions or recommendations for other tools or libraries, and those types of questions are explicitly defined as off-topic in the site help documentation.

Comment: lol ------------

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Have you read through the site guidelines?

Comment: Man I've been googling for two weeks trying to find a simple way to implement a window to display rapidly updating text data in python that doesn't scroll. I finally broke down and decided to create an account to ask the question to the community and I'm told I can't ask that question. I don't know any other way to ask it that's more succinct - I have very limited coding knowledge. No I did not read the guidelines. I'll just assume it isn't possible and try something else instead. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Of course it's possible. Any GUI toolkit will be able to update data without scrolling, and likely be able to do it dozens of times a second if you wish. Though, updating more than once every second or two becomes a usability issue.

Comment: Do you know that until that comment I hadn't even considered updating the display at only 1-2 hz instead of at the actual data acquisition rate? That should solve my problem. I'll retry with a Canvas widget at a slower frequency. I'm also looking at using Numpy arrays instead of Python lists because it looks like they're faster. Thank you.